# linear regression predicts lower than expected

Tags: regression, predictive-models, least-squares, scikit-learn

I am trying to predict first term GPA for college students based on a number of incoming factors (high school gpa, placement test, year). This isn't the overall model just a simpler one. The first term GPAs are on the interval 0 to 4, however the predictions from the linear OLS model (i'm using sklearn) never go above 3.6 (see picture). Is this some sort of gotcha that I am missing? There are certainly data in the training set with first term GPA that is between 3.6 and 4.0. I didn't expect perfect performance but this is odd to me.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the model diagnostic plots?

Comment: i added model diagnostic plots. i think the cooks distance is wrong though because i had to calculate it myself because i didn't find any function outside of statsmodels that implements it and i havent written tests or compared it to output from R, statsmodels, etc.

Comment: Just by looking at the first (diagnostic) plot you can see that your model is fu****. Your dependent variable is limited to 0 and 4 so a regular linear model is not valid.  Look into beta regression. Also, do you have repeated measures in your data? As in, do some students have more than 1 score? Is there any kind of correlation going on?

Comment: yeah this is my thinking as well and will check out beta regression. students should only have a single score although some are averages (e.g., the output variable is the first semester GPA which is the average of several scores).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Predictions like these don't include the 'error' in your model: that is, you expect that even if your model is very good, a student with some combination of predictors will not be exactly the prediction, they will be above or below it. The only way you would get a prediction of 4 would be if a combination of predictors gave an estimate that the *average GPA for that observed combination* would be 4. If the average GPA for that observed combination is 3.6 with a range of 3.0-4.0, your model would predict 3.6 even if you would expect some fraction to have 4.0; your best guess for each individual student is the *expected value*, the mean. If you instead imagined your predictions as *probability distributions* you would find that these include 4.0.

However, it looks like your model itself is not very good: there is a lot of difference between your predictions and outcomes and very little slope between them relative to the variance.

Comment: Yeah I agree that the model is not very good. I guess I got stuck on maximum prediction value, and wondering why it wouldn't be higher than trying to tune it into something that is predictive.

Comment: @Krause I very much need a formal citation for the argument you make clearly, about variance of predictions being lower than variance of obs.  I have tried hard to find a paper(s) but so far without success.  Suggestions please?  Does the concept have a name on which I might search?  Thank you.